# How can I shorten this JavaScript if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I want check if all elements of an array are different from undefined. `array_main` contains 9 elements.

I've created an `if` as below:

```
// Function checking is there a tie - 0:0
var check_if_tie = function () {
    if( array_main[0] !== undefined && array_main[1] !== undefined && 
        array_main[2] !== undefined && array_main[3] !== undefined && 
        array_main[4] !== undefined && array_main[5] !== undefined && 
        array_main[6] !== undefined && array_main[7] !== undefined && 
        array_main[8] !== undefined ) {
        alert("TIE!/REMIS!");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('Continue playing');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Is it possible to shorten this `if` somehow?

Comment: what are the other possible values of the array?

Comment: other possible values of the array are 0 and 1

Comment: @p7adams, i was the first who provided the solution using `every` method. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to iterate over every element from the `array_main` array, you can use `Array#every`.

It will return `true` if **every** element from the given array fulfills the `!== undefined` condition. If at least one element doesn't pass it, it will return `false`.

```js
var array_main = [1,2,3];

var check_if_tie = function() {
  if (array_main.every(v => v !== undefined)) {
    alert("TIE!/REMIS!");
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('Continue playing');
    return false;
  }
}

check_if_tie();
```

Comment: array.every() function helped me solving my issue.  
Here is part of my script, which works for me properly.
    // Function checking is element of array diffrent from undefined.
    var check_if_tie = function (element, index, array) {
    return (element !== undefined);
    }

    // Function checking if there is a TIE.
    var display_if_tie = function () {
 array_main.every(check_if_tie);
 if( array_main.every(check_if_tie) ) {
  setTimeout(function(){alert('TIE/REMIS')}, 600);
 } else {
  assign_zero();
  console.log('Continue playing');
 }
    };

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of way you can do this.One of then is checking the index of undefined.

```js
var array_main= [1,3,4,54,5,undefined,4,54]
if(array_main.indexOf(undefined) > -1) {
  alert("TIE!/REMIS!");

} else {
    console.log('Continue playing');

}
```

Comment: I think I shoul use some kind of a loop inside this if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `every` method which accepts a `callback` method.

```
array_main.every(function(item){
    return item != undefined;
});
```

You can also use `arrow` functions accepted by `ES6`.

```
array_main.every(item => item!=undefined);
```

Here is a short example:

```js
var array_main = new Array(9).fill(undefined);
console.log(array_main.every(function(item){
    return item != undefined;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var check_if_tie = function(){
    for(elem in array_main)
    {
        if(array_main[elem] == undefined)
        {
            alert("TIE!/REMIS!");
            return false;
        }   
    }
    console.log("Continue playing");
    return false;
};
```